# Which processes write to /var/adm/messages

Tags: linux, unix, operating-system, solaris, daemon

What are the processes that write to "/var/adm/messages"?
From what I gathered Syslogd does the job. Am i right?

Also I saw multiple files, messages, messages.0,  messages.1 and so on. Why is it so?

Also is there any other system process that writes to these files?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, processes that use the syslog framework send messages to syslogd, which reads `/etc/syslog.conf` to determine where (or if) the message should be written based on the *facility* and *level* of the message.  For example, if `syslog.conf` has the entry

```
user.debug     /var/log/mylog
```

then all messages of a higher *level* than `debug` (the lowest level) from processes of the `user` *facility* (i.e. non-system processes) will be sent to `/var/log/mylog` (`man syslog.conf` for full explanation including possible facilities and levels).

The `/var/adm/messages.X` files are created as `/var/adm/messages` is rotated by the `logadm` cron job (again, see the man pages for `logadm` and `logadm.conf`).

**NOTE**: This answer is based on Solaris experience; file locations and behavior may vary with other *NIX flavors.

Comment: thanks, your solution worked.
I still don't get why my question is not related with programming (off topic)?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out yourself with dtrace:

http://dtracebook.com/index.php/File_Systems

> Syscall write(2) by file name: dtrace -n 'syscall::write:entry {
>   @[fds[arg0].fi_pathname] = count(); }'